# Selection of table with flexdashboard

Tags: r, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I am work with flexdashboard.I already find some tempalate example (https://jjallaire.shinyapps.io/shiny-biclust/ ) and now I want to adapt in accordance with my needs. But I face with one problem.

Namely here I already used reactive function and below you can see my code from function.

```
num<-reactive(as.integer(input$clusterNum)
```

Selection here is made with selection number from 1 to 5. After selection from drop down menu and select one of number from 1 to 5, this selection going to next block of code and select appropirate cluster. You can see code below

```
renderTable(
  BicatYeast[which(res@RowxNumber[, num()]), which(res@NumberxCol[num(), ])]
)
```

So far so good. But now I want to try to use this kind selection on my data. My dataset is list with two tables (table 1 and table 2) . You can see how is look in R.

[image]

Now I want to use same command for selection of my data and I tryed with command line

```
data[which(num()]
```

but this not work.
So can anybody help me how solve this problem and select table 1 of my list ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how to display one table of the list:

```
library(shiny)

# example data
data <- list(
  iris,
  ggplot2::mpg,
  iris,
  iris,
  iris
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("clusterNum", label = "Cluster number", value = 1, min = 1, max = 5, step = 1),
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data[[input$clusterNum]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```